# ClamAV GPU installation

Tags: 14.04, clamav

I need to use ClamAV in GPU under ubuntu. There are some papers related to it. But how can i install ClamAV such that it could run in GPU? Can anyone help me with installation steps?

Comment: Do you mean GUI?  Otherwise that would be some really fast virus scanning.

Comment: no its not about gui

Comment: i need to run clamav with GPU support.. Where can i get the source code for it?

Comment: All I can find is outdated literature showing it's capabilities, but never in a production release.  'We have modified ClamAV, the most popular open source antivirus software, to utilize our engine. Our prototype implementation has achieved end-to-end through-put in the order of 20 Gbits/s, 100 times the performance of the CPU-only ClamAV, while almost completely offloading the CPU, leaving it free to complete other tasks.'  I think your question is outside the scope of askubuntu.

Comment: I also read this paper. There are implementations. but i dont know where can i get it and how to install clamav along with gpu support

Comment: but where can i get the help other than askubuntu?

Comment: Graphics Processing Unit for massive parallel use to enhance speed of reliable applications

Comment: Interesting concept. You should update your question to indicate that this is experimental and you will likely have better luck on the nvidia or ati forums depending on your graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that technology is experimental at the time of this writing and unpublished in the repositories. No luck there, sorry.

Comment: **David: You're losing it!** (You're showing up in the LQ review queue) +1 to get you out!  **;-)**